# jquery datatables change td class for empty table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables plugin. (https://datatables.net/) I wanna know if there's a way to change the TD class when the tables is empty.
From what I saw when there are no rows in table datatables inserts a row with a TD with class `dataTables_empty`  . Is there way to change *dataTables_empty* to *myDataTables_empty* ?

I'm using `fnRowCallback` to change other rows classes... but it seems that this is not working for the auto inserted row when the table is empty.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the plugin you are using, like a link to where you got it from?

Comment: Would you be able to supply some sample code for me to try, as I am not familiar with this plugin. Alternatively you could create a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Have you tried just searching through the code and replacing `dataTables_empty` with `myDataTables_empty`?  Why do you care about changing the name anyway, why not just work with the class name provided?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I can do that. the problem is that I have multiple tables on one page, for #table1 and #table2 and every table has it's own style

Comment: @DouaBeri Then just provide separate CSS treatments for id/class combinations like: `#table1 .dataTables_empty { ... }`. Apply these rules after base `.dataTables_empty` rule to override any styles you want to change on a table-specific basis.

Answer (score 0):

you could change it using jQuery quite easily.

in your (document).ready handler...

```
$('.dataTables_empty').removeClass('dataTables_empty').addClass('myDataTables_empty');
```

Alternatively you could just use the default class name and override it in your CSS.

Otherwise, take a look at the [datatables doco](http://datatables.net/styling/ids_classes)...

Comment: this might work. but do you know if there's an event  or a callback when the table is empty. The reason I'm asking for this is that users can manually add/ delete rows from table and sometimes the table gets empty, and every time the table gets empty datatables is setting the class dataTables_empty

Comment: Im not too sure. If the class is added when you delete the last entry then yes, there is an event handler for it. If it is only applied if the table is empty on load, then perhaps not.